# Match anything before a certain pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have string that can contain almost any character including `(_- %` and so forth. The string ends with `(\d{1,2})`. Eg. parenthesis with 1 or 2 digits. I now want 2 capturing groups, the 2 digits and everything before the parenthesis.

currently I have:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([-%\\(\\)_/= a-zA-Z\\d]+)\\((\\d{1,2})\\)$");
```

But this does not match everything. I want to replace the char group with `.*` but not have it match the `(\d{1,2})` at end of string. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The question isn't clear.. show us sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question, you can use a reluctant quantifier `.*?` instead of your greedy quantifier `.*` to match everything *reluctantly* before your second catpure group.